# React-route-dom updates url but doesn't render component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a react material-ui react component that I want to use to render another react component by changing the url.
Create Jobs is a component in another file.

I have looked at many of the other questions about this on SO, and none of them solved my problem.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import CreateJobs from './CreateJobs'
import MuiTable from './Components/MuiTable'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ListRunConfigs_urls(){
  return(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path = '/Jobs' component = {ListJobs}/>
      <Route path ='/Jobs/Create' component ={CreateJobs}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  )
}
...
function ListJobs(props) {
...
  const createButton = 
    <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Button 
        component={Link} to='/Jobs/Create'
        variant="contained"
        color="primary">
        Create Jobs
      </Button>
    </div>
    return(
        <> {loading ? (
        <Grid
            container
            spacing={0}
            alignItems="center"
            justify="center"
            style={{ minHeight: '90vh' }}
      >
    <CircularProgress size="10vh" />
    </Grid>
    ) : (
      <MuiTable 
        model="Jobs" 
        createButton={createButton}
        />
    )}
    </>
    );
}
```

List jobs properly renders but when I press the create button, the url changes to "localhost:3000/Jobs/Create", but the `CreateJobs` component doesn't render. When I click the url and hit enter, the correct component does render.

Comment: In router use `exact` property for the parent url components routing to make sure that, it won't redirect the first fetching route. You can check in React router [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/exact-bool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding exact to the jobs one:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path = '/Jobs' component = {ListJobs}/>
      <Route path ='/Jobs/Create' component ={CreateJobs}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: It worked thanks. I thought I had already tried this but for some reason it works now and it didn't before

Answer (score 1):

Just swap your Routes around since React router will try to match in this sequence, i.e `/Jobs/Create` matches your `/Jobs` Route:

```js
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path = '/Jobs/Create' component = {ListJobs}/>
      <Route path ='/Jobs' component ={CreateJobs}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```